# Which editor can locate a file quickly by typing the file name?

Tags: windows, file-search

I want to find a simple editor which can let me locate a file quickly by typing the filename, just like the `Ctrl+Shift+R` in eclipse.

I tried a lot just now, but found only a few of them can do this, but they are not free. Is there any editors are free and can run in windows?

Following can't:

1. notepad++
2. notepad2
3. scite
4. ConText
5. jEdit

Following can, but not free:

1. sublime

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings:

- Vim with plugins for [searching files](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Searching_for_files) (e.g. [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984), [find-complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4426), [asyncfinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4198)).
- TextMate (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>); e.g. *Reveal File* In *Project Drawer*.<sup>[source](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-quickly-find-a-file-in-the-project-by-filename/4572)</sup>
- Sublime Text 3 (<kbd>Control/CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) in *Where* you can type the filename, or map the custom shortcut.
- In Terminal: `find . -name "*some_name*"`.